# Preloader show on my local host but not showing after deployed on github?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

See below is my code, I used below code and after deploy on github pages preloader now working.
Showing one error message in console status.gif after deployed but it not showing in local host

Github Link:- https://github.com/mohit421/Portfolio

Why?
**CSS code :-**

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:var(--clr-light); /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
    z-index: 999999; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

#status {

    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
    top:50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
    background-image:url(/img/status6.gif?); /* path to your loading animation */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; /* is width and height divided by two */
}
```

**HTML code :-**

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){        
        $('#preloader').fadeOut();
        $('.preloader_img').delay(150).fadeOut('slow'); 
    }, 5500);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give us the link to your github page? The code you have postet is basically running on a codepen, so we would have to inspect the actual page where it's not working

Comment: https://github.com/mohit421/Portfolio

Comment: @MohitJaiswal You need to use *`https`* in your jQuery library call. `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: Still getting same issue.

Comment: After deploying on netlify with same code it work ,
Check :-https://mohitjais.tech

Answer (score 1):

Your GitHub page: https://mohit421.github.io/Portfolio/ is not working because you are loading the jQuery library URL with no HTTPS.

So, you have this error in Chrome console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mohit421.github.io/Portfolio/' was
> loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
> 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'. This request has been
> blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

See the image below.

[image]

You need to use **`https`** in your jQuery library call.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your preloader div before the "closing body tag". Set the preloader position absolute and set the body position relative. Finally set the preloader height to 100vh.